# Port Forwarding in DLINK ADSL Router

Tags: web-development, web-services, networking, web

I am currently using DLINK DSL-2520u Modem to test my web site by locally hosting and checking it over internet.

As it is a single port router I have only attached one pc,(Which is at 192.168.1.2) to the internet.

I can't understand two parameters asked in the screen **Server IP** and **Remote IP** ,What are the values i have to give in order to forward port to my pc to host the web site,

[image]

Comment: Not the right place for this question.

Comment: You cannot host a website like this.. which webserver are you using? what is your OS?

Comment: this questions is appropriate for serverfault.com moderators need to migrate this..